# Is it possible to do running correlation with one fixed series in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I'm wondering if there is a fast way to do running correlation in Python with one fixed series? I've tried to use Pandas and for example:  df1.rolling(4).corr(df2). However, it requires two DataFrames to have the same length.
Is there a way to do similiar to the above Pandas example, but with one DataFrame being fixed?

To clarify, I would want to calculate the correlation coefficent between df2 below and the values in df1.

Example:
First correlation between df2 and df1.loc[0:3]
Second correlation between df2 and df1.loc[1:4]

etc.

I've managed to do this by creating a loop. However, I find it inefficent when working with larger DataFrames.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,3,2,4,5,6,3,4])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) which returns
`pandas.core.window.Rolling` which has [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) method. Then you could pass to `apply()` any function that calculates the correction you want.

#### Example

- Let's say you are interested in the [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient). That can be calculated using [scipy.stats.pearsonr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html).

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr 
import numpy as np 


df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,3,2,4,5,6,3,4,1,2,3,2,2,3,2,5,1,2,1,2,8,8,8,8,8,8,8])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,2])

CORR_VALS = df2[0].values
def get_correlation(vals):
    return pearsonr(vals, CORR_VALS)[0]

df1['correlation'] = df1.rolling(window=len(CORR_VALS)).apply(get_correlation)
```

- Note that the `window` argument in the `df1.rolling()` should have the same length as the array you are calculating correlation against.

this outputs

```py
In [5]: df1['correlation'].values
Out[5]:
array([        nan,         nan,         nan,  0.31622777,  0.31622777,
        0.71713717,  0.63245553, -0.63245553, -0.39223227, -0.63245553,
       -0.63245553,  1.        ,  0.        , -0.70710678,  0.81649658,
        0.        ,  0.47809144, -0.23570226, -0.64699664,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.7570333 ,  0.76509206,  0.11043153, -0.77302068,
       -0.11043153,  0.86164044])
```

which would look like this:

[image]

Comment: That’s amazing. Thank you! Previously, i’ve used loops with .iterrows() but this is much faster and efficent!