# Is it possible to do running correlation with one fixed series in Python column-wise instead of rows?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, pearson-correlation, scipy.stats

I asked a question here two months ago ([Is it possible to do running correlation with one fixed series in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62942889/is-it-possible-to-do-running-correlation-with-one-fixed-series-in-python)) where I recieved great help from a fellow user.

My goal is to do running correlation with one fixed series in Pandas. This can be achieved with the code below which works rowwise. However, my objective is to do this columnwise. So instead of testing correlation row for row, I want to run a correlation test for each column. Any help is appreciated!

```
#Method to do running correlation rowwise.
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr 
import numpy as np 

# running correlation, one fixed series (rows)
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,3,2,4,5,6,3,4,1,2,3,2,2,3,2,5,1,2,1,2,8,8,8,8,8,8,8])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,2])

CORR_VALS = df2[0].values
def get_correlation(vals):
    return pearsonr(vals, CORR_VALS)[0]

df1['correlation'] = df1.rolling(window=len(CORR_VALS)).apply(get_correlation)
```

However, my objective is to do this columnwise.

Then my data would look something like this:

```
values = {'column1': [7,2,3,1],
        'column2': [1,5,2,3],
        "column3" : [2,5,2,5]
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(values)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([2,3,4,3])

print(df1)
   column1  column2  column3
0        7        1        2
1        2        5        5
2        3        2        2
3        1        3        5

print(df2)
   0
0  2
1  3
2  4
3  3
```

My desired output would be like this:

```
Out[71]: 
          0
0 -0.620920
1  0.239046
2  0.000000
```

Comment: Im guessing this could somehow be done with pd.corrcoeff. However, the lengths naturally dont match

Comment: Could you just transpose the dataframe before running the code?

Comment: My head isn't working with me today.. Of course that works.. However, any ideas on how to perform running correlation with several columns?

Comment: Does it work when you pass `axis=1` to apply?